# Rampant Google Play Services and Location problems since Nougat 7.0 Update on LG Stylo 2

Tags: google-play-store, google, 7.0-nougat

I have an LG Stylo 2 running android on Virgin Mobile.

Since the Nougat OTA has been rolled out a week or two ago, I have had numerous and far-reaching problems with the device, and troubleshooting each of these problems individually has been unsuccessful.

The worst/most annoying are:

- Constant "google play services has stopped" or even "google play services keeps stopping" messages.
- Frequent messages "authentication is required" messages in the play store asking me to log into my google account, though I am logged in (this also happens in other apps, and it won't take me to a login screen)
- Huge issues with location and GPS. Location is on, and when I try to toggle the mode to "high accuracy", it automatically toggles back to "GPS only".
- Same with the ***Qualcomme IZat*** performance improvement service:

  - When I turn it on, it just turns back off. GPS occasionally works with google maps if I boot up the GPS status app, but will not work at all with location-based apps like "Pokemon Go".
- I am also unable to use the LG backup service.

**Things I have tried:**

- Rebooting phone/taking out the battery multiple times (this actually makes the "google play has stopped" messages more frequent after reboot for a while).
- Clearing data and cache for google play services and google play store, as well as all cache on the phone, multiple times.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling all of the apps with issues, including google play services and google play store.
- Disconnecting and reconnecting my google account (this gave me numerous errors trying to reconnect the account

  - It took me many tries. and I was worried I would never be able to reconnect the account initially.
- "Force Stop" Google Play Services and Google Play Store
- Toggling Airplane mode and location on and off.
- Checking for updates to Firmware/Phone etc. Daily!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.